# Show TeeChart on local Report

Tags: teechart

Is there a way to show a TeeChart on a Microsoft Report (rdlc)?  I am not using a Report Server, simply a C# application with TeeCharts that that I want to show on a simple report.  I have looked at the  "Readme_TeeChartReportingServices.htm" file that has been mentioned in some Forums, but I think that is strictly for use with a Report Server.

Answer (score 0):

TeeChart for Reporting Services just creates a Bitmap and inserts it into the report. So you could [export an image with TeeChart](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/net/tutorials/html/TeeChartProNetTutorialsContentsTutorial12-ExportingandImportingCharts.htm) and embed it into your report.